# The code shows no error on compilation,but it doesn't show any output

Tags: c, windows

The program is very simple , it gives the greatest common divisor as the output.I have verified my algorithm.The compiler issues no error ,but still it wont produce any output.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int gcd(int ,int );
int main()
{
    int a,b,j;
    printf("enter two numbers");
    scanf("%d\n",&a);
    scanf("%d\n",&b);
    j=gcd(a,b);
    printf("gcd is %d",j);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int temp,c;
    if(x<y)
    {
           temp=x;
           x=y;
           y=temp;
           }
    if(y<=x&&(x%y==0))
    return y;
    else
    {   temp=x%y;
        c=gcd(y,temp);
        return c;

        }
}
```

Comment: FYI: usually, if you have `x > y` on entry, then the first iteration (recursive call) fixes the problem, so you don't need the special case for that.  Also, in general, you'd use an iterative algorithm rather than a tail-recursive algorithm.  (Would you have guessed that GCD(34533, 1279) == 1279?  Nor me!)  Also, the `scanf("%d\n", &var)` operations should be error checked and the `\n` at the end means you have to type some non-white-space character after the second number before the input terminates.

Comment: @Karanv.10111 regarding `scanf` and `\n` you can read this question in clc FAQ http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
scanf("%d\n",&a);
scanf("%d\n",&b);
```

Delete the `\n`, just

```
scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&b);
```

is OK

Answer (score 2):

This could be due to buffering of the output. Add `\n` to your `printfs` and see if it fixes it:

```
printf("enter two numbers\n");
printf("gcd is %d\n",j);
```

Alternatively, you can add calls to `fflush(stdout)` to flush the output buffer:

```
printf("enter two numbers");
fflush(stdout);

printf("gcd is %d",j);
fflush(stdout);
```

---

Other than that, it (almost) works as intended on my setup:

```
enter two numbers
4783780
354340
1
gcd is 20
```

The only thing is that the `\n` forces it to read an extra character. (which I chose to be `1`)

Comment: Yes, but the stdio buffers are flushed anyway when the program exits, no ?

Comment: The OP has a `getch();` that prevents it from exiting. (I think...)

Comment: @Karanv.10111 Can you give some more details on how it doesn't work now?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
printf("enter two numbers");
```

doesn't print a newline character (`\n`), and so the output isn't flushed to the console.

Try adding this after the `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d\n",&a);
scanf("%d\n",&b);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c",&a);
scanf("%d%*c",&b);
```